# Is there a mistake in the name of the [qudit] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I found a tag named [qudit](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qudit) that was tagged in [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1468/is-quantum-computing-limited-to-a-superposition-of-only-two-states).

I highly suspect this might be a spelling mistake for qubit, since the question is also tagged with [qubit](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qubit), and no other question has this tag. However I’d like to confirm this, as I’m quite new to quantum computing, and not very familiar with the terms used in such.

Comment: While a qubit is a vector in a 2D space, a *qudit* is in $d$-dimensions, so it's all good! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Similar to the qubit, the qutrit is the unit of quantum information in 3-level quantum systems. This is analogous to the unit of classical information trit of ternary computers. The term "qudit" (quantum digit) denotes the unit of quantum information in d-level quantum systems (normally 3 or more).

Source: [Variations of the qubit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubit#Variations_of_the_qubit)